# Change dot to image for UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have learnt recently that UIPageViewController is a good way to manage a multi-page scene and its built-in dot function is a good way to indicate the current page which is displayed.

But I wonder if I can change the dot system to something like images.

The reason asking is that I came across this app scene:
[image]

This scene consists of 3 views "details", "due date" and "budget", which are indicated by 3 "label"-like elements in the header. You need to click the button "continue" in the bottom to navigate forward. And when the page changes, the label corresponds to the current page is highlighted while the others are greyed out.

Really curious how this can be achieved. Do they change the dot to images or they just put up those static labels to the corresponding page's header section?

Comment: They could be using a different framework. You can check https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material which uses this feature. This UX is very much android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you shared is not using `UIPageViewController`. It is using `UISegmentedControl`.
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) is the link for Apple documentation.

Comment: I can tell that the "yes" and "no" element in the bottom right corner is UISegmentedControl. But the three tags just beneath the "post a task" title does not seem UISegmentedControl to me. As they are not clickable, all they do is to switch from "highlighted" state to " not highlighted" state to indicate if the page they correspond to is being displayed. The page changing event only happen via tapping the big green "continue" button at the bottom.

Comment: Apple does not allow `UIPageViewController`'s page indicator to be changed. At best, you can change their color. Even if someone managed to hack into the underlying library to exploit this functionality, I'm quite sure that Apple would reject such an app. My best guess is that this app DOES use `UISegmentedControl`, disables user interaction, and then uses gesture recognisers to switch between different view controllers. This would give the illusion of it being `UIPageViewController`